# How to show additional data in tooltip at each point on time series graph in Grafana

Tags: time-series, tooltip, grafana

I need some help with tooltips on time series graph in Grafana. I am executing a kusto query which projects these 3 values: date_time (timestamp), data (int), and build_id (string).

Using this query, I am creating a time series graph. By default when i hover over any data point on the graph, i can only see data value as tool-tip. I also want to show build_id along with data on hover. In future, I might need to include more information in this tool tips information.

any workaround to get this working in grafana for now?

Comment: AFAIK not possible with a time series graph. Possible with bar chart if that is an option.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using timeseries visualization you have the option to configure tooltip:

[image]

When you change from *single* to *all* you will see multiple values in the tooltip.

[image]

Comment: You have show three lines and three data in tooltip. I want to add more information and data from each line. Like maybe in total 3 data informations from each line.